# Как общую таблицу связать с дочерними с сохранением целостности и корректности данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных, структуры-данных

Реляционная схема данных.
Есть таблица `обращения`. Обращаться могут как `люди`, так и `фирмы`, это разные сущности и отношения в БД. У `обращений` много атрибутов, все одинаковые, кроме собственно того, кто обращается.

У меня вариант пока такой. Создать отношения `Обращения от фирм (ид_обр, ид_фирм)` и `Обращения от людей (ид_обр, ид_люди)`, которые будут связаны один-к-одному внешним ключом с основной таблицей `обращения`. А в запросах просто объединять три таблицы.

Все бы хорошо: при добавлении обращения я автоматически добавляю нужную запись в одну из таблиц соответственно. Также я могу правильно связать все таблицы.

Но при таком подходе база в теории позволит хранить неправильные данные. Например, я могу руками в таблицу `обращения от людей` добавить запись с таким `ид_обр`, которое уже будет присутствовать в таблице `обращения от фирм`.

Подскажите, есть ли более удачный способ хранения таких данных? Такой, при котором база данных будет сама обеспечивать правильность и целостность данных и не будет отношений вроде `ид, тип_этого_ид`.

Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы!

Comment: Я бы попробовал уйти от двух разных таблиц, людей и фирм. Например, завести одну типа "субъект" с полем "тип" внутри. Ещё одну рядом с типами. Ещё одну с описанием свойств субъектов и одну многое-ко-многому для значений этих свойств. Можно даже "тип" туда же убрать, а не держать рядом.

Comment: В таблице  обращений делаете 2 поля - FK на людей и FK на фирмы. Контролируете, что одно из этих полей - NULL. Увы, триггером - MySQL не обслуживает CHECK Constraint :(... на всякий случай, дабы не было "зависших" сообщений - контролируете там же, что второе поле не NULL. Ну то есть что `man_id IS NULL + firm_id IS NULL = 1`.

Comment: @Akina да, это и был первоначальный вариант, который пришел в голову. Стал думать, как сделать так, чтобы избежать этих пустых полей. То есть в целом в подобных ситуациях такая схема является нормальной практикой?

Comment: *Стал думать, как сделать так, чтобы избежать этих пустых полей.* ну да, ещё одна таблица, конечно, лучше, чем ещё одно поле...

Comment: @Lexx918 спасибо, по идее интересно, но сложно реализовать в текущих условиях, да и типов субъектов может быть больше..

Comment: @Akina честно говоря, не подумал, что можно триггером отменить insert... А можете подсказать: если будут еще какие-то типы обращающихся, целесообразно действовать так же и менять условие триггера?

Comment: Да понятия не имею... единственное, что могу сказать - постарайтесь уже сейчас придумать таких "обратителей" и заложить их в схему. Или хотя бы количество - сунуть заранее пару незаюзанных полей, добавить ещё слагаемых в триггер, и пусть себе лежат, NULLы копят, пока не надобны. Ежли понадобятся - так всего и делов, что FK нарисовать. Потому как править живое гораздо больнее будет.

Comment: Да, триггеры рисуйте не только на пополнение, но и на обновлёж - а то частник запросто может в организацию превратиться...

Comment: @Akina спасибо вам, буду думать =)